# html_nodes("table") returns {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from the following webpage.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/campaign-zero-use-of-force/index.html

I am using the following code:

```
page <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/campaign-zero-use-of-force/index.html"
pagina <- read_html(page)
pagina %>% html_nodes("table")
```

I expected the script to return a table on the webpage but it returned {xml_nodeset (0)}. I don't know why it's not seeing a table on the webpage. Thank you.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Hi Nico, I expected that html_nodes("table") return a table element. However, it returned {xml_nodeset (0)}. I want to extract the table on the webpage along with the clickable content each row. Thank you.

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it